# Can't Get Email Content using FuelSDK and Python

Tags: fuel-sdk, python

I am running the basic example of getting Email content through the FuelSDK package in Python, but the results always come back empty.  I am able to get results back for different types of events (clicks, opens, sents, etc.), but Email results are empty.  I've tried with and without a date search filter.

Am I missing something?

import FuelSDK

stubObj = FuelSDK.ET_Client(False, False)

getEmail = FuelSDK.ET_Email()

getEmail.auth_stub = stubObj

getResponse = getEmail.get()

results = getResponse.results